# How can I modify a customized build class derived from build_py so that it builds in a temporary directory?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils

I have a setup.py file with a customized build class derived from build_py, which is imported from either distutils (for older setups) or setuptools:

```
try:
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', 
        message='.*distutils package is deprecated.*', 
        category=DeprecationWarning)
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.command.build_py import build_py
except:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py

class MyBuild(build_py):

    #... existing custom code here...

    #... new custom code here...

    def run(self):
        build_py.run(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    setup(
        name="...",
        version="...",
        #...
        cmdclass={'build_py': MyBuild}
    )
```

I've run into the problem that when running from a VM client (though oddly not when running outside the client), `pip install .` fails, apparently because it tries to set up a build directory within the source directory and this fails due to permissions issues. Other people have found `pip install .` failing under different circumstances. For what it's worth, I'm using Python 3.11 on Windows, and I've seen the failure with both pip 22.3.1 and pip 23.3. **(UPDATE: I see the same problems with Python 3.9 and 3.10. Using older versions of pip causes another problem: "ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections".)**

I was thinking that I could retrieve the name of a temporary directory via `tempfile.gettempdir()` and set the build directory to this value. The problem is that I can't quite figure out how to do this based on the [distutils documentation](https://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/distutils.cmd.Command-class.html), the [Setup tools documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/extension.html), and existing examples elsewhere on the web, including Stack Overflow. In particular, I'm not clear on how `initialize_options`, `finalize_options`, and `set_undefined_options` are supposed to work and whether I should be using `set_undefined_options` at all.

I tried this code, inserted where `"#... new custom code here..."` is located in my example above:

```
    def initialize_options(self):
        self.build_base = None
        self.build_lib = None
        print('Set self.build_base and self.build_lib to None')
        
    def finalize_options(self):
        if not self.build_base:
            self.build_base = tempfile.gettempdir()
            print('Set self.build_base to ', self.build_base)
            
        if not self.build_lib:
            self.build_lib = os.path.join(self.build_base, 'lib')
            print('Set self.build_lib to ', self.build_lib)
```

But then I got an exception when I executed `pip install .` in the directory containing the setup.py file:

```
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [55 lines of output]
      Set self.build_base and self.build_lib to None
      Set self.build_base to  <...>\AppData\Local\Temp
      Set self.build_lib to  <...>\AppData\Local\Temp\lib
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\pyvenv\<...>\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\pyvenv\<...>\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\pyvenv\<...>\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 138, in <module>
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 318, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 326, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 548, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 586, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 113, in add_defaults
          super().add_defaults()
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 249, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_python()
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 125, in _add_defaults_python
          self.filelist.extend(build_py.get_source_files())
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_py.py", line 303, in get_source_files
          return [module[-1] for module in self.find_all_modules()]
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_py.py", line 293, in find_all_modules
          if self.py_modules:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-42o2vdhl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: py_modules. Did you mean: 'find_modules'?
      [end of output]
```

I tried adding this line to the end of `finalize_options`:

```
        # self.set_undefined_options('build_py', ('build_base', 'build_base'),
            # ('build_lib', 'build_lib'))
```

but this just got me into a nasty recursive loop.

What should I be doing instead?